# Django auth: How to disallow user session if his IP doesn't match the original one(the one he logged in with)

Tags: django, django-authentication

How can auth can be configured or modified to disallow user sessions if the user's IP is not the same IP that he logged in with ?
I really try to protect my Django site from XSS as much as I can. But I never can be sure that I covered all the bases. If worst comes to worst and someone is able to put some XSS in my site, at least this could prevent him from hijacking existing user sessions..

Comment: I can't see how this could prevent XSS, but I can see how this will prevent users from using your site from dynamic IP or a laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your User model class create an IP field that stores the IP address of the request.

`original_ip_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`

then before serving a view simply check the current request with the stored ip:

```
if request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] == ip_from_database: `
# Do something
else:
 #redirect to login
```

you can make the above a function that is always called before anything else in a view.

Comment: Make sure to update the ip on every successful login attempt or to delete it after a logout, else they might not be able to come back.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following just to be sure you are getting the real IP address of the visitor and not that of the proxy or the load balancer. (just in case your server is behind one)

```
# on login:
request.session['logged_ip'] = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
                                request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP',
                                 request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '1.2.3.4')))

# on each request
if (request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP',
    request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '1.2.3.4'))) != request.session['logged_ip'])
    # don't allow
```