# django one session per user

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-1.1

based on docs ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/http/sessions/ ) (yes - 1.1) Django creates unique sessions to all users. Logged user contains `_auth_user_id`. How can i achieve such check in login:

```
If new_login._auth_user_id in database:
   delete(sessions_containing_same_id_except_new_one)
```

The main idea is to allow only one session per user and delete old 
sessions.

**UPDATE:** The idea right now is to save sessionid while logging and if sessionid changes delete old entry before replacing. ATM missing part is to get that session id.

**UPDATE:** I got the sessionid with `request.session.session_key`. The problem was that sessionid is created *after* login. If you request key before it was created - it creates new one instead of giving any warning.

Comment: Similar to question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379353/django-auth-how-to-disallow-user-session-if-his-ip-doesnt-match-the-original-on)

Comment: @StephenPaulger, its based on IP. From single office all PC's comes with the same IP. There fore i'm searching info about sessions. I almost know what to do, but i can't get session_key since `request.session.session_key` creates new key instead of taking current.

Comment: That was linked to from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814437/allow-only-one-concurrent-login-per-user-in-django-app) the second answer may be what you're looking for then.

Comment: @StephenPaulger it answered a lot and i learned what to ask for google and where to look (to the source) :D. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created extra field for user (userattributes extends user):

```
class UserAttributes(User):
    last_session_key = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=40)
```

and method:

```
def set_session_key(self, key):
    if self.last_session_key and not self.last_session_key == key:
        Session.objects.get(session_key=self.last_session_key).delete()
    self.last_session_key = key
    self.save()
```

and i called it just after login:

```
auth.login(request, user)
user.userattributes.set_session_key(request.session.session_key)
```

Comment: Don't forget to import Session
`from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session`

Comment: simplest answer I found... one caveat... Session.objects.get(session_key=self.last_session_key) result should be checked before delete()

Comment: hi @JackLeo, I tried to implement this but I'm getting this error ```User has no userattributes```